# Is $\mathbf 0$ an element of $S = \{ \mathbf u_1, \mathbf u_2, ..., \mathbf u_k\} \subseteq\mathbb{R}^n $?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S = \{ \mathbf u_1, \mathbf u_2, ..., \mathbf u_k\} \subseteq\mathbb{R}^n $. Which of these statements are true?

Comment: 0 is a scalar, not a vector. So C is true $\iff$ at least one of the $u_i$ is equal to $0$. D is not true unless the $0$ in D means the vector $\mathbf{0}=$ {$0,0,...,0$}

Comment: I think u1, u2,..., uk are general vectors, the question didn't specify one or more of them to be 0. I am not sure if 0 is referring to  a scalar or vector. {u1, u2, ... uk}, v1, v2 and 0 were bolded in the question. So, am I right to assume 0 refers to the zero vector, and is not a scalar? If 0 is a vector, then B, D and E are correct right (assuming none of u1 - uk are zero vector)?

Comment: Anything in bold means vector, anything not in bold means scalar.

Comment: I bolded the vectors correctly, you can read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference so that you can do it yourself in the future

Comment: Thank you! I just want to confirm that E is correct because 1/pi is a real number, so (1/pi)v is a valid linear combination?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbf{v} = $ { $v_1,...,v_n$ } $\implies 1/ \pi \ \mathbf{v} = 1/ \pi$ { $v_1,...,v_n$ } = { $ v_1 / \pi, ... ,v_n/ \pi$ }, which is a member of span(S).

Answer (score 0):

The scalar $0$ and the vector $0$ are different but how the difference is indicated, if at all, varies.  Some use bold e.g. $\mathbf{0}$.  Others use an over arrow e.g. $\vec{0}$.  However, often the reader is left to guess from the context.

You need to check what convention your course or book is using.  If it has a consistent convention then you can answer C.

For E, $\frac{1}{\pi}$ is a scalar so $\frac{1}{\pi} \mathbf{v}$ will be in the span.

Comment: Thanks, will remember to differentiate them in the question.

Comment: It is more important how they are distinguished by whoever asked the question.